# TransientVariableInstance cannot be cast to VariableInstanceEntity

Tags: activiti

Activiti6
I have a workflow that only contains the servicetask node. I set a transient variable at the start node. After the workflow is all executed. A type conversion exception was thrown inside activiti.

```
public class TestDispatcher  implements JavaDelegate {
    
    @Override
    public void execute(DelegateExecution execution) {
         execution.setTransientVariable("test", "123");
    }
}
```

This file reports an error。

ExecutionEntityManagerImpl line569  // Get variables related to execution and delete them

```
if (!enableExecutionRelationshipCounts || 
        (enableExecutionRelationshipCounts && ((CountingExecutionEntity) executionEntity).getVariableCount() > 0)) {
      Collection<VariableInstance> executionVariables = executionEntity.getVariableInstancesLocal().values();
      for (VariableInstance variableInstance : executionVariables) {
        VariableInstanceEntity variableInstanceEntity = (VariableInstanceEntity) variableInstance;
        
        VariableInstanceEntityManager variableInstanceEntityManager = getVariableInstanceEntityManager();
        variableInstanceEntityManager.delete(variableInstanceEntity);
        if (variableInstanceEntity.getByteArrayRef() != null && variableInstanceEntity.getByteArrayRef().getId() != null) {
          getByteArrayEntityManager().deleteByteArrayById(variableInstanceEntity.getByteArrayRef().getId());
        }
      }
    }
```

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.TransientVariableInstance cannot be cast to org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.VariableInstanceEntity

Comment: Is it necessary to have a waiting node to disable the transient variable before the end of the process？

Comment: it seems like a bug from activiti

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was facing this error because transient variables were being set and the end event was getting executed immediately.

So, I fixed it by adding an execution listener to one of the sequence flows just before the end event.

```
<sequenceFlow id="flow77" sourceRef="signalintermediatethrowevent1" targetRef="exclusivegateway9">
  <extensionElements>
    <activiti:executionListener event="take" delegateExpression="${removeTransientVariables}"></activiti:executionListener>
  </extensionElements>
</sequenceFlow>
```

You have to write a listener class as well to remove the transient variables:

```
import org.activiti.engine.delegate.DelegateExecution;
import org.activiti.engine.delegate.ExecutionListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class RemoveTransientVariables implements ExecutionListener {

    @Override
    public void notify(DelegateExecution delegateExecution) {
        delegateExecution.removeTransientVariables();
    }
}
```